# Issues within an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application to Look for When Running on Linux with Mono

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

My IT department and I are trying to get an ASP.NET web application to run on a Linux with Mono.  We have been working on this for about a month to no avail.  The Mono setup on the Linux server seems to be good.  We are able to run the demo ASP.NET pages on the server and they work fine.

I developed my ASP.NET web application with Visual Studio 2008, and I recently downgraded the application to ASP.NET 2.0.  Originally it was in ASP.NET 3.5, which might be the problem.  After publishing the web app, I received the following files: Default.aspx, Web.config, bin (with a .dll and a .pdb file), and an empty App_Data file.  So far, the error that keeps occuring is an appication error on the server.

For a simple test, I made a simple ASP.NET web app that had a label and a button.  We tried that app and it did not work either.  Does anyone know of things that I should look for within my ASP.NET web application that would inhibit the application to work?

Application error:

Description: An application error occurred on the server.  The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. this  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

!--web.COnfig Configuration File--
configuration
  system.web
    customErros mode+"Off"/
  /system.web
/configuration

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

!--Web.Config Configuration File--
 configuration
  system.web
    customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/
  /system.web
/configuration

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: You're going to have to provide the application error in order for us to understand this one.

Comment: Thanks grenade - I added the error; however, it looks like it has nothing to do with the application; I don't know.  I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: You did read the error message, right?  It tells you exactly what you need to do to find the real error.  In fact, it tells you two different methods of obtaining the real error.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a resolution, I finally figured out what the problem was.  The ASP.NET web app has an onload event that enables the web app to read an Access Db.  For testing purposes, I did not update the ADO.NET Db path for the web app to read the Db so every time it was loaded through Mono, the generalized error in question would occur.  After deleting the onload event, the web app functioned perfectly.  Additionally, I had to downgrade the web app to ASP.NET 2.0, instead of 3.5, and delete the LINQ namespaces, which were not being used.

All I have to do is change the path(s) to point to the App_Data folder and place the Db in the folder, as well.

Comment: As an FYI, Mono supports C# 3.0, and LINQ.